# Stack Exchange needs its own anti-spam system

Tags: discussion, feature-request, flags, spam-detection, robots

This is not a duplicate of [Should Stack Exchange have a spam filter? (Does it already and I’m not aware?)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310355/should-stack-exchange-have-a-spam-filter-does-it-already-and-i-m-not-aware) which is asking if there's already a system in place.
I am asking for a review of the existing structure, which relies heavily on volunteers, and breaks abysmally when those volunteers withhold their efforts.

---

I'm aware of our current anti-spam structure - [Charcoal](https://charcoal-se.org), [Charcoal-HQ](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq) & [Metasmoke](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/flagging). I'm also aware of large explanatory info sources about this - [A machine can flag spam automatically. Can it do better?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307585/a-machine-can-flag-spam-automatically-can-it-do-better/307613#307613) and similar.
Also ref recent questions from other users who weren't aware of this setup - such as [How can we handle spam faster?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/390506/how-can-we-handle-spam-faster)

And, before anyone else links to it - this is the SE blog telling us how good the spam protection already is - [How does spam protection work on Stack Exchange?](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/06/25/how-does-spam-protection-work-on-stack-exchange/) - written by one of Charcoal's leaders, [ArtOfCode](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/262823/artofcode).

What the astute reader may also notice is

1. In addition to SpamRam [about which I can find very little] it already relies on Charcoal, and
2. When Charcoal is off you get this, multiple times a day…

[image]

<sup>Click for full size</sup>

What I ***wasn't*** aware of until only this week, is that it seems to be entirely volunteer-run.
That the volunteers don't currently wish to engage is already part of a larger issue, which I don't want to add to here.

It's time Stack Exchange had its own spam filtering.
How could this be practically achieved? Does the company have any plans to implement a viable structure, rather than relying solely on the goodwill of volunteers?

The first thing that springs to mind is that we already benefit from a system that works reasonably well under normal circumstances. So, my first suggestions would be…

**License the structure & pay for it.**

Alternatively, or in addition,
**Change the number of human flags to just three, or even fewer, if detection heuristics put it above say 98% spam already.**

I am not, btw, advocating we just hand this whole task, lock, stock & barrel to any form of 'AI' & remove human checking.

I'm open to other suggestions.

Comment: They do already have a system - see https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/06/25/how-does-spam-protection-work-on-stack-exchange/

Comment: For the record, Philippe was recently promising to compensate Charcoal for our hosting costs. That's obviously a fair bit less than the objective cost of actually maintaining the system; we normally have a substantial number of volunteers who donate their time and know-how in the form of updates to the patterns, the actual code, our documentation, etc etc.

Comment: @greg-449 - yes… it sits heavily on Charcoal, as mentioned. When Charcoal is down it's next to useless. Added to question.

Comment: @tripleee - thank you for the additional information. I have to admit, I didn't know who you were three days ago - all this 'behind the scenes' discovery is very recent for me; even though I've been here 9 years. Thank you for the work you & the other volunteers do. :)

Comment: And, at the risk of restating the obvious, https://github.com/Charcoal-SE/ is entirely open source. If the company wanted us to run ops for them, it's not clear how you would compensate a loosely-knit network of volunteers on at least four continents to render  a service, or create a legal agreement to govern this arrangement. Given recent devolopments, it is uncertain that the volunteers who are currently on strike would be willing to return.

Comment: Amusingly, being a single point of failure and *much too efficient* was an early reservation I had of charcoal. And don't forget even if they ran the *software*, and did flagging themselves, they'd still need to have the 'rules' for detection volunteers provide. This *won't* work without the community, and... a couple of years on, maybe that's a good thing.

Comment: That screenshot is precious. It proves the strike works, and should be sent to the board of managers of Stack Overflow Inc. They should see what their actions cause, and even them with their narrow view should understand people don't want to visit such sites, and they will lose lots of money if this will be going on. So no, I'm against SE making their own anti spam system.

Comment: @ShadowWizardStrikesBack - shame I didn't think of getting the screencap earlier, when I had an entire screen-full of similar.  This is far from being a record, just one of a dozen times a day I see it. It comes in waves. The largest wave for today is perhaps over, based on recent patterns. There will be more, but unless they're learning there shouldn't be another page-full until tomorrow.

Comment: Re *"Stack Exchange needs its own spam system"*: Sure. Just let ChatGPT generate questions and answers. It will get the numbers up.

Comment: Where is that screenshot from? It is worse than YouTube comments.

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum - Super User a couple of hours ago. No filter, just 'by newest' so that's what the entire first half of the page was. It's been worse, I just didn't get a screenshot.

Comment: @RobertColumbia - no it doesn't. I'm aware of SpamRam [which I've now added to this question, it was already linked in the blog post]. My thrust is more, "Why are we reliant on the goodwill of a volunteer-based system?"

Comment: Around 6AM British Summer Time (05:00 UTC) there was a massive wave of spam. I was honestly impressed at the sheer quantity of it. I think spammers have taken note that the effectiveness of Stack Exchanges spam filtering system has decreased somewhat and are taking advantage. I have no current way of investigating how they're doing it, whether by multiple IPs or other means as I'm effectively locked out of looking at PII (Personal Identifiable Information) such as emails and IPs by the strike, but I'm worried how much SE relies on community effort and they don't realise.

Comment: Why do machines if you have almost unlimited supply of free slave labor? It's the same effect that lead to the technological backwardness of Eastern Europe from XVI century - absolute no incentive for innovation.

Comment: 'Why are we reliant on the goodwill of a volunteer-based system?', people like *free* whenever possible; regardless of the real cost. --- and some people have worked for free for over a decade: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/moderator-resignation  that's the business model, the company pays for the equipment and supplies the software (and intervenes where moderation is insufficient) and everyone helps themselves for free (or by being subjected to ADs). There is a [Satisfaction Survey](https://stackoverflow.az1.qualtrics.com/jfe/form/SV_b14eaLcRaiLlZMF?Code=LOG&Rep=1k&Age=110).

Comment: @Tetsujin It sounds like you are moving the goalposts. First you suggest that a first-party anti-spam system is needed, I point out that one exists, and then you edit the question to explain why you don't like the one we have. Also, SpamRam is aided by Charcoal activities but isn't functionally dependent on them - it can work just with old-fashioned community flagging.

Comment: If your real proposal is that SE pay Charcoal participants, don't hide it in a bunch of generic stuff about needing better spam-handling. State your proposal and provide the rest as justification.

Comment: @RobertColumbia - 'old-fashioned community flagging' is what produced the picture in the question. The 1st party solution is obviously nowhere near good enough on its own. You seem to be missing the whole point of my question. What makes you think I'm 'hiding' anything?

Comment: @Tetsujin Old fashioned community flagging needs a motivated community to pitch in.  The sort of folks who would be unhappy with SO inc's current actions. We'd be able to manage say charcoal being down a week or so - but it would be a mix of people like me who are less involved in these things, and people who would be on charcoal anyway. Every solution still needs the community somehow

Comment: @JourneymanGeekOnStrike - I should have stuck with my original title, "***Why*** doesn't SE have its own effective spam system?" to which we all already know the answer. It was cheaper to let someone else do it.

Comment: ‘the existing structure, which relies heavily on volunteers, and breaks abysmally when those volunteers withhold their efforts’ — which is what gives the strike any chance of being effective. Why are you proposing to take that away?

Comment: Your latest edit basically describes how Charcoal's autoflagging feature works. Even with a higher threshold than you propose, it gets false positives from time to time. Some of this could be remediated with a redesign to reduce overlap between detection reasons (for example, a post in Chinese will trigger two heuristics, "majority non-Latin text" and "Chinese text", which for legacy reasons count as distinct). It submits multiple flags automatically when a particular threshold is exceeded, rather than reduces the number of required flags, which of course it can't; the net effect is the same.

Comment: I love that image of the homepage in your question because while SO inc is out chasing AI in any possible way, like implementing some fancy [AI formatter](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/425081), it can't even detect the **exact** same title being posted ***5*** times in less than 5 minutes...

Comment: And the system is also so helpful, limiting us to 25 flags a day... so if there is a community member trying to assist by flagging they should quickly be outrun by the spammers 

Comment: It’s much more effective to the let the volunteers handle spam. We handle all sorts of low quality content. Sometimes it just happens to be spam. So we handle it accordingly. The majority of the garbage we manually handle, is _not_ spam. So to have dedicated staff only hunting down spam? They’d waste a lot of resources for all the time spent at looking at stuff that’s garbage, but not spam. A lot of the stuff that gets reported to us as potential spam (by CHQ’s bots) isn’t actually spam; just garbage in some way. Sometimes we catch spam that the bots didn’t even consider potentially being spam

Comment: @YisroelTech You get 100 daily flags once you’ve proven yourself to be a good flagger. It’s automated.

Comment: Instead of complaining about the spam, you can always join [the strike](https://openletter.mousetail.nl/). The more pressure you put on SE, the more likely they are to meet our demands, which’ll make us return. Not that I have any trust and belief that they’ll meet our demands, anymore.

Comment: @AndreasdetestsAIhype - I've so far refrained from discussing the strike… but, the trouble with strikes is that, no matter your support for the cause, the people they really hurt are the ones who *use* a service, not the ones who *own* it. See how much support the UK's recent rail & bus strikes had… very little, because the people who were hurt the most were the ones who couldn't get to work.

Answer (score 45):

I'd argue that it would be *very* difficult to replicate [Charcoal](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/06/25/how-does-spam-protection-work-on-stack-exchange/) without a fair amount of effort.

You *can* automate flagging and removal. However the 'rules' used to detect spam are manual, community-generated, and verified, and since spammers are consistently creating new patterns, you'd still need to be able to accurately identify spam, and verify to ensure there are no (or at least *minimal*) false positives, and take the appropriate action.

While an 'official' tool would have certain advantages, such is potentially being able to use 'historic' information and PII such as email and IP addresses, and since SE's so very enthusiastic about GenAI and machine learning maybe they could write one, The company *hasn't* yet, and you'd still need training data - both historic and current to make better matches. Which might involve needing people to flag anyway.

Basically, it comes down to whether the cost of winning over the community is cheaper than writing a new tool or letting the network get overrun by spam.

Or we have a tool that literally costs the company nothing but treating its most enthusiastic members right (but of course, support would be welcome) and has proven itself to be so efficient the network suffers spam outbreaks when it's down. *And* its devs have worked with the company in the past.

It's their call, really.

Comment: It’s trivial to replicate all the Charcoal systems as they exist today. It’s expensive to keep them up to date as spam evolves.

Answer (score 36):

SpamRam is a system that I designed which works on an account and network level. From what I understand, it has received some upgrades over the years, but it's essentially fed from user and moderator activity such as flags, account destruction and other events. It also has some "honeypots".

None of these systems function unless humans are pointing at things and saying "That's bad!" ***and people with the most privilege that a community can bestow are following through on those reports.***

I don't think it's even feasible to create something autonomous at the scale of Stack Overflow because the investment required would be indistinguishable from a seed round to develop that kind of product.

Answer (score 0):

At the time of this edit, the question state is closed as a duplicate of [Should Stack Exchange have a spam filter? (Does it already and I’m not aware?)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/310355/289691). I don't think that it should be closed as a duplicate of such a question, as this question already mentions **SpamRam**, the Q&A public platform system used to fight spam, among other things.

It looks that the purpose of this question is to propose to the company to take measures to have an anti-spam system that doesn't depend on volunteers, more specifically, that doesn't depend on Charcoal and the *moderators*, understanding moderators as community members that have earned moderation privileges, in this case, the privilege to flag posts as spam.

Why limit the public Q&A platform to getting its anti-spam free of volunteer participation? Why don't you go full throttle and suggest using GenAI to make the public Q&A platform free of volunteer posts?

To be clear, the above are rhetorical questions to express that if the company does something like that, then the company might still own brands (Stack Overflow, Stack Exchange), domains (stackoverflow.com, stackexchange.com, superuser.com, askubuntu.com, etc.), software and hardware, but Stack Overflow and the Stack Exchange network, as they exist nowadays, will no longer exist. Period.

Eliminating the flag privilege and preventing volunteer participation led by Charcoal members to fight spam in the Q&A public platform will change the core of Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange.

---

##### Explanation of the hypothetical suggestion

By "going full throttle" to "take advantage of using GenAI", I mean to use it to post questions and answers; no "Ask Question" or "Answer" forms for user input will be required anymore, and spammers will not be able to post spam directly.

Using content crawlers / miners and GenAI, the company might scan real existing communities, and code repositories, among other sources, find out what questions are in the wild and answer them, posting questions and answers on their platform.

The company will no longer need a community team to handle the relationship with question-and-answer posters and moderators.

If the company finds a way to do it right, it might not need an anti-spam system...

... but they should find a way to handle [AI hallucinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hallucination_(artificial_intelligence)).

Please note that I'm not suggesting the above to the company; it's just a thought exercise to help understand that the company should not prescind volunteer participation in fighting against spam.

Comment: Because, **that's not how "genAI" works** and because **genAI is a completely inappropriate tool for this application**. "GenAI", or generative AI, is a very specific *type* of AI (i.e., *machine learning*). "GenAI" has *very specific applications*, which, frankly, it does a good job at. But those *very limited jobs* are **not general purpose artificial intelligence** (and don't included even generating *factually accurate* output text, at least at the current level of the technology).

Comment: So, yes, AI/machine learning could be quite useful (and some effort has been made to use AI/machine learning by people associated with Charcoal, with mixed results), **but it's *not* "genAI"**. *Please don't fall into the hype that "genAI" is universally applicable to every situation*

Comment: @Makyen, I'm sorry, but I am not following you. Probably it's my fault, and the breach between my thoughts and words is causing a misunderstanding. I edited the answer to clarify the use of GenAI that, in a rhetorical sense, could someone might suggest. I'm not saying that this hypothetical suggestion is viable or has sense.

Comment: Rubén, I don't understand how the company using genAI to post questions and answers has *anything* to do with preventing/combating spam, unless you're *also* saying that the company should completely stop taking questions, answers, and comments from users. If there's an input box that people can use to have their custom text shown to other people, particularly shown to the general public, then there *will be* spammers and trolls using it to post inappropriate things. The overall system needs to be able to handle that by removal/prevention/sanctions, or just not allow any input from the public.

Comment: @Makyen Yes, the hypothetical full-throttle suggestion implies that the company removes the input boxes, hence, SO/SE will no longer exists, even if the URLs are still used to publish content.

Comment: btw, no-one ever mentioned *preventing* community participation at all.

Comment: Well, sure, removing user input from the equation will remove spam. But then we might as well stop eating food to reduce waste. It's not a solution.