# Can we experiment to use AI for moderators?

Tags: feature-request, moderators, humor, ai-tools

With the risk to be severely downvoted and thrown to Hell by the existing human moderators, here is a heretical idea:

---

***Replace all moderators by AI-ones, making the life of the former much happier, calm and creative***.

During my 16+ years of membership at SO, I have sometimes witnessed moderators whose behavior strongly reminded me of Daleks (from "Doctor Who").

If being a moderator carries the risk of converting one to a Dalek, then replacing a human moderator with an AI would bring them real happiness, security and a stronger and more well-founded value system.

**I know, this may sound provocative**, so, *please, bear with me, take a deep breath, calm down and think about this rationally. Suppress the urge to answer immediately, take a 2-3 day "leave" from all (meta) SO-related things, and then come upon this again* :)

---

**Update**: Seems that many readers either didn't understand the post or completely ignored the advice to "*take a deep breath, calm down and think about this rationally. Suppress the urge to answer immediately, take a 2-3 day "leave" from all (meta) SO-related things, and then come upon this again** :)"

**Just in the first 10 minutes after publishing, there are 9 comments and 10 downvotes** :)

Impressive even for Daleks, isn't it?  :)  :)  :)

Note:  I also added the tag ***Humor***, to set the context in a definite way ...

Comment: Hey folks, I'm locking this question for a day. It seems like any prospects of productive conversation here played out within the first few hours, and I'm struggling to see a productive purpose for continuing the conversation now. And if you do see one, then I think it can wait a day. I'll clean up some of the comments, though I don't want to step on Meta mods' toes here. After the lock expires, please make sure what you're adding to the conversation says something that a) hasn't already been expressed, and b) _actually needs_ to be expressed.

Comment: Unrelated to question itself, but very interesting: Based on edit history, I see you really want to save big red thing in the post, but I'm missing it's purpose. Can you explain why it's there and why do you think it does what it does better than built-in horizontal line?

Comment: This can be researched [by going](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/391485/can-we-experiment-to-use-ai-for-moderators#comment1308750_391488) [to Quora](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/390106/moderation-strike-update-data-dumps-choosing-representatives-gpt-data-and-wh/390150#comment1302678_390150). It already happened there, long before ChatGPT (several years).

Answer (score 22):

It's unclear to me whether you intend this question seriously or as a joke but it seems like a reasonable opportunity either way for me to say some things related to this.

From very early in our history we made the decision that **moderation should be done by people**, not automations. We've often stated that, though it's not always known - and we actively discourage moderators - many of whom are excellently knowledgeable and capable programmers - to avoid automation of their tooling. We encourage them to use or create tools that *support* their efforts and make them simpler or more streamlined but we do not want them acting without human oversight.

There are some things we do automate. These things are generally well-known by community members and makes it so that when others who are not aware come across them, the actions can be explained. This includes things like:

- [Deleting some questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/auto-deleted-questions) that are old or poorly received.
- Invalidating votes in very extreme cases (which we don't explicitly reveal the rules for but it's generally known).
- Preventing or limiting participation on the site based on a variety of factors.

But, more frequently, we don't automate the decision-making; we automate drawing attention to cases that may be concerning, either to moderators or other community members with certain privileges. This includes things like:

- (on SO) [flagging comments identified as unfriendly with a bot](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/04/09/the-unfriendly-robot-automatically-flagging-unwelcoming-comments/) we trained and implemented.
- raising flags for large volumes of edits, post deletions and other cases to moderators directly.
- adding posts identified as potentially low-quality to review queues.

---

I was a moderator at one point in time and making decisions about how to act on flags, how (and when) to communicate with users, and what to invest my time in were all really complex things to figure out. While I haven't been a mod for almost five years, I've been a CM for that time and have worked closely with mods to better understand their concerns and, particularly within the last year, work with an internal team to create new and better tooling for them.

In that time, there has been some discussion about what could be automated but it's never in the interest of replacing moderators. As with our guidance to them, we want to make their efforts simpler by giving them more context or helping draw attention to more issues so they don't have to go searching for them on their own.

While there may be cases where we identify things that we can automate completely, the likelihood is that this will be limited to (as it is now) very clear cases that really don't require moderator intervention and we'll ensure the mods and community are in agreement that these automations are reasonable.

There are several reasons for this -

- We highly value moderation by humans, particularly people with close ties to the communities they moderate.
- We do not want to *replace* moderators with AI both because AI is prone to errors and because we recognize that moderation is very complex and beyond the capabilities of any current AI.
- We have a general understanding with the communities that moderation will be done by humans.

All of these come together into the idea that the complexity of moderation requires human intervention because understanding a situation fully can't be done by computers - AI or otherwise - particularly when you remember that we have 180+ sites with site-specific rules and expectations from users.

Humans may not have the memory or data immediately to hand, which is why supporting mods with improved tooling is something we are putting a lot of effort into - but I don't think anyone wants us to have bots misunderstanding interactions between users and deciding to suspend them for behaviors that aren't actionable.

We see this already - while we went to a lot of effort to collect data and train our unfriendly robot, one of the reasons we haven't shipped it network wide is that we've received regular feedback from the SO mods that it flags many comments that aren't even close to being rude. If it just deleted all of the comments instead of flagging them - it'd be removing potentially important information in the comments that a human moderator would have recognized and retained.

So, I'll say it one more time:

We feel human moderation is important and not something that AI can do. While we may look into options that use AI to help or support moderators, that is the extent of what we are considering.

---

NB: While I don't speak for the moderators, I will say that no one is forced to be a moderator here or to remain one. Mods don't have terms and they're not required to complete a specific period of activity. If a mod decides that they no longer want the role, we let them step down and, if the other mods need more support, we run an election to find a new moderator.

As such, while your concern for the mods is commendable, I hope that the mods already understand the situation and feel like they can bow out whenever moderation is too stressful or is no longer fun for them.

Comment: A comprehensive response! I intended this question as an experiment to gauge the current sentiment towards and understanding of the current-state AI. Not every organization is so critical of the current and impending AI, see for example this article about Wikipedia considering AI in the context of collecting/verifying/curating knowledge: https://medium.com/freely-sharing-the-sum-of-all-knowledge/wikipedias-value-in-the-age-of-generative-ai-b19fec06bbee . And not all AI is created equal, the latest example being PI, who is curious, supportive listening and empathetic: https://shorturl.at/EJTZ8

Comment: So much said which I wanted to say, expressed with clarity I'd never achieve. As an extra note, having been on Steam forums for a while I've had several bans, and deleted content, issued by their "bot" moderation system. Each one has been reversed, with the content restored; but only after I directly appealed the decision and got a human involved. In the midst of an ongoing discussion, a few hours spent waiting on human corrections is quite a mess, and each time I question whether or not to continue on that platform. Making SE/SO into the same mess is unprofessional, at best.

Comment: Moderator bots with unspecified IQ have already been a reality on [Quora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quora) for several ***years*** (with catastrophic results; it only takes a few hours of [being subjected to the actions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/390106/moderation-strike-update-data-dumps-choosing-representatives-gpt-data-and-wh/390150#comment1302678_390150) of these moderation bots to realise that). The company embarrassed itself by having the creators on the podcast one or two years ago.

Answer (score 14):

### What?! No. Absolutely not.

Think about the *massive* number of tasks mods do regularly (or, when not on strike, anyways). Mods are "human exception handlers". While the accuracy of this statement today is debatable (and beyond the scope of this answer), there's still a large number of tasks mods do that can't be automated with gen AI. I.e.,
they deal with issues when normal systems can't. Like voting fraud when the automated scripts can't. Or voting rings. If we could easily automate mod tasks with 100% accuracy (or *extremely close*), it would have been done already. One example of this is handling sock puppets and voting rings. While the specifics aren't public (and won't be), that is... not something that can be done by AI. Neither is handling the queues. Plagiarism flags can't be automated. Many custom flags require a level of investigation and knowledge of SE that can't be automated. For example,

> user12345 is involved in a voting ring with other users (user1, user2, user3), and is now posting abusive material directed at a moderator in the chatroom called ABC. Can you investigate this and deal with the users involved as needed? Thank you!

Good luck getting an LLM to properly handle that. It can't. Certainly not *properly*, at least.

Sure, I could cherry pick a case where it would (maybe) handle one flag correctly. But at scale? For thousands of flags?

Also, we're not a site ran by AI. And let's keep it that way by not giving diamond mod powers to gen AI and creating evil AI overlords.

Gen AI it can't look at much of the facts mods can look at - previous history, PII, etc. Even if it could, **AI can't make well-reasoned, educated choices that are evidence-based and justifiable like mods can**. It's a black box.

I had posted [an answer somewhere else on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/391061) explaining why gen AI is a terrible choice for spam flags, much of the same logic applies here.

Comment: I do see a case for AI to _support_ moderation. Machine Learning systems could help discover voting rings, for example. I do not see a case for LLM's in moderation, though.

Comment: @S.L.Barthisoncodidact.com Agreed, and using ML for data analysis to gives mods potential users to investigate is something that _could_ work (in theory, at least). But as you said, that's _massively_ different than "Replace all moderators by AI-ones", as the OP stated

Comment: "Use AI just for support" i wonder what other operations on this site that this can apply to, which the same people DV'ing this question are also opposing

Answer (score 9):

**The real problem with this idea is that AI is *not* intelligent.**

Humans understand other humans.  The best moderators know how to cope with difficult people (including me).  Through millions of years our brains have evolved to understand other humans (and dogs, but not cats).  We spend our lives learning skills in politics, negotiation and psychology so we can find our way through the adult world with a minimum of pain.

"AI" isn't intelligent.  It's just about barely capable of pattern matching tricks.  It has no idea how to calm down a situation, when to use a stick, when to use a carrot and when to use a bazooka.  It doesn't have the slightest clue how to deal with people.

Worse, humans are also very good are thinking up new and often insanely complicated ways to argue their case and even try and game the system.

Moderators have to be able to cope with those sneaky human users and their shenanigans.

Humans are good are dealing with humans, even the sneaky and devious ones, the obsessives, the ones that think everything is a philosophical argument, that everything is a conspiracy or the ones that think their human rights are being violated by the most trivial rules requirements.  It's not fun for humans to deal with other humans who do these things, but they're generally able to do it.

So-called AI just isn't able to deal with this kind of thing.

And it's a long, long, long, long way from anyone producing an AI that could manage that.

Never mind them taking over the world, AI couldn't win an argument for a coffee break with my boss.

Comment: How do you define "intelligent"? Not quite long ago one of the most prestigious photo awards was given to a photographer who then revieled this was a work of an AI tool.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev _I_ define 'intelligent' in part by the ability to 'reason'. Inb4. _I_ define 'reason' as the ability to think and understand. AI currently lacks the ability to 'think', or to 'understand' and therefore has no 'intelligence'. Perhaps that's why it's called '_artificial_' intelligence; because it's fake, not real, only a seeming simulation of _intelligence_.

Comment: What I would not call intelligent is faking an image.  That's something humans can do better anyway.  Plenty of fake images have been passed off as real by humans.  We even have a word for it, it's so common : "forgery".

Comment: @Chindraba_on_strike Sorry, but you are replacing one undefined concept with two. Intelligence, conscience and cognition are not yet completely understood (scientifically), thus these are to some extend subjective. If something can acquire new knowledge and learn, the difference becomes even more fuzzy. Is playing chess a creative, intelligent activity? Who plays chest best at present? I am sure we cannot provide complete and exact answers to such questions just in a Meta comment thread, but these are good food for thinking.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev Playing chess, a task with a well defined goal and set of precise rules, and dealing with largely unpredictable behavior from people are just completely different levels of complexity.

Comment: I don't see any of the three concepts as being 'undefined' and as they have definitions in several dictionaries, none listed as "probable", I'll consider them as 'defined.' Whether or not some entity possesses or utilizes those concepts can be, however, debatable. I've often wondered that in regards to many of the humans I meet. "Understanding" a concept - scientifically or otherwise, is not required for a definition of it. WRT 'intelligence', the ability to simulate it does not equate to possession of it. Likewise, the acquisition of knowledge is not intelligence. Encyclopedias have #1 not #2

Answer (score 8):

As a moderator - and this is something I *sometimes* feel the company often loses sight of, quite a lot of what I do is *people*.

Moderation is not just dealing with flags, spammers and smiting. It is *community leadership* - and to borrow/steal the words of Alexis Ohanian, one of the founders of reddit

> which means (mostly) listening, starting productive conversations, role-modeling the behavior you wanna see in your spaces.

And a bot can't really do these things.

And a *great* community leader inspires, holds things together, *earns* trust and influence and tries to use it for good. They understand the struggles of the community. I joke much like [Samuel Vimes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sam_Vimes), a great moderator's covered their site so much they know every cobblestone by feel.

> During my 16+ years of membership at SO, I have sometimes witnessed moderators whose behavior strongly reminded me of Daleks (from "Doctor Who").

Ironically I think empathy is an *essential* tool for a moderator, but we *also* often come across some situations so routinely we have what feels like a dispassionate/almost robotic response, but one that's been honed by years of use.

I'm happy to reach out to people - obviously subject to my ability to dedicate the time,effort and mental health (cause sometimes even I need a break) and be reached out to through the appropriate channels

> Just in the first 10 minutes after publishing, there are 9 comments and 10 downvotes :)

Most of these people aren't moderators anywhere.

But this seems less a compelling argument for GenAI moderation than  a way to say "I don't like how they are moderating *me*".

Also I have never once stuck a plunger on someone, fresh or used, whether or not saying "Exterminate" in a robotic voice.

Comment: Re: "And a bot can't really do these things.". Have you tried using Pi: https://heypi.com/talk

Comment: A bot can't reach out to a user and let them know we're watching out for them. A bot doesn't have context of the community and its norms. There's a lot of community work that involves people trusting *you* and your ability to understand, empathise and occasionally creatively problem solve.

Answer (score 5):

Judging from [WeAreDevelopers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/391338/stack-overflow-at-wearedevelopers-world-congress-in-berlin), new uses for AI are coming to Stack Exchange.  However, replacing moderators (literally described as [human exception handlers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/site-moderators)) in their entirety is infeasible and certainly unwelcome.

If we want to find uses for AI that have a chance of being welcome, I suggest starting with things that don't fundamentally change how sites operate:

- Replacing "enter image description here" with useful text.
- When someone is suggesting a duplicate, an AI could read both posts, and write a sentence explaining how the questions differ (or not).  Or possibly, an AI might be able to automatically cast a "Does this answer your question?" vote to close (assuming it could be done with high accuracy) which could more efficiently help the OP, and save users from answering duplicates.
- An AI "not an answer" detector which warns the user before the non-answer is posted, or if that's not feasible, auto casts "not an answer" flags like Smoke Detector does for spam.
- Write a kind of "what's news at [site].SE" blog post, giving a summary of site activity (both at the main site and on meta), summaries of interesting questions, users who have reached milestones, and so on.  And post it on social media (like the Twitter bots, but better).
- Have an automated English proofreader, something like a built-in Grammarly.
- Automatic tag wiki/excerpt generation.
- I also don't mind the idea of automated questions under certain circumstances, such as puzzles.  E.g., AI-generated images could be used on language sites as a kind of "writing prompt"---users can write about the image in their target language.
- Turn "2021: a year in moderation" meta posts into an infographic, which shows how things have changed over time.

I'm just brainstorming here, but hopefully you get the idea.  AI should help users, either by automating things they don't want to do (tedious, time-consuming tasks), or by facilitating users in making Q&A.